# Sculpting issues on a model

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

When trying to sculpt a model, it seems that none of my brushes are very effective no matter what settings I'm trying. Is this possibly a vertex count issue or am I missing something? I've tried changing strengths, changing brush stroke from spacing to airbrushing, and various different brushes. I do not have a drawing tablet, so I've turned this setting off. It is my first time sculpting so any information would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnxobrn8k3lrhik/pug%20assassin%20with%20a%20suit%20and%20shadesrev5%20-%20Copy.blend?dl=0

Comment: From what I see ... just press F in Sculpt mode and move a mouse to enlarge brush size (Radius) like 170 px to see effect.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of you attempting to use the brush on a model, and what the results are?